# Validate fields by processing array inside useEffect reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am checking some validations for empty text fileds. Here is how I am doing that.
I have an array, where inside the map function I am checking for empty fields. If I find an empty field I am pushing a value to another declared array.After processing the first array, I checked if the second array length is greater than zero. If so I had initialized a variable to 1.
And I disabled the button if this length is greater than zero.

```
let optionsArray = []
{questions.map((x, idx) =>
  questions[idx].options != null
    ? questions[idx].options.length == 0
      ? optionsArray.push(idx)
      : questions[idx].type == "list"
      ? questions[idx].options.map((x, id) =>
          questions[idx].options[id].value == "" ||
          questions[idx].options[id].value == null ||
          questions[idx].options[id].value == undefined
            ? optionsArray.push(id)
            : ""
        )
      : questions[idx].type == "rating"
      ? questions[idx].options[0]?.rating == 0
        ? optionsArray.push(2)
        : ""
      : ""
    : ""
)}

if (optionsArray.length > 0) {
var isOptionNull = 1
} else {
var isOptionNull = 0
}
```

I am disabling the button if isOptionNull == 1 like below

```
          <Fab
          color="secondary"
          aria-label="Save"
          disabled={isOptionNull == 1}
          >
          Okay
          <Icon>okay</Icon>
          </Fab>
```

This is working fine. But now I need to do this inside react's useEffect. I am new to react js. How can I use the code there and disable the button accordingly.

Comment: You can try this.
1) move the above map logic inside a function
2) inside the useEffect, invoke this function.

Comment: Also, you want to invoke this function every time, once or upon when a state is changed ? you can define all those in dependency array of useEffect.

Comment: I wrapped my above array map code into a function and inside useEffect I called the new function. Then outside useEffect if I checked the variable isOptionNull, it always return 0.

Comment: Whenever my optionsArray has value I need to set isOtpion to 1. So that I can check whether if this is 1 disable the button.

Comment: Declare your variable isOptionNull outside useEffect.

Comment: yes it is outside but still no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These pages will probably help: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

This should run whenever questions gets updated with a new value something like:

```
const [isOptionNull, setIsOptionNull] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
    let optionsArray = []
    questions.forEach((x, idx) => {
        if(x.options && x.options.length === 0) {
            optionsArray.push(idx)
        } else if(x.type === 'list') {
            x.options.forEach((y, id) => {
                if(!y.value) {
                    optionsArray.push(id)
                }
            })
        } else if(x.type === 'rating' && options[0]?.rating === 0) {
            optionsArray.push(2)
        }
    })

    if (optionsArray.length > 0) {
        setIsOptionNull(1)
    } else {
        setIsOptionNull(0)
    }

}, [JSON.stringify(questions)])
```

Comment: But this always returns 0 right.What I have written is if optionsArray.length > 0 , then isOtpionNull == 1. And  in my button I need to check whether if ,isOption==1 then disable the button.

Comment: I've updated the code. This should run every time questions list gets updated. You can then check if isOptionNull == 1

Comment: Worked . Thanks :)